# Can't get 2.9 to work

Tags: miktex

I just downloaded MiKTeX 2.9.  It seems to install correctly, but when I run files that worked fine on an earlier version, I get two problems:

First, TeXworks gives me a Layout Problem message "caused by an issue in the underlying Qt framework."  Second, when I run the file, I get a message that says, Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.  There is no .pdf output.

I have tried installing (with reboots) several times. I have a Win 10 system.

Any suggestions, anyone?

Many thanks --

Kent

Comment: It is unlikely that we can help you here. This site is mostly used for the purpose of understanding TeX coding questions, rather than software installation questions. Looks like you need to take your question to MikTeX. But you might try the portable version of MikTeX, and see if that works better.

Comment: Can you run pdflatex on the command prompt?